# monorepo fronend projects with kubernetes solution

Tags: javascript, docker, kubernetes, frontend, monorepo

Deal with several frontend projects before, that normally I release the static files to AWS S3 bucket with AWS CDN cloudfront (or Azure Storage with Azure CDN) or others, such as heroku, vercel, etc.

But this time, the developer want to deploy both frontend and backend in a kubernetes cluster (**I don't understand the reason, why this design, but let's not discuss at this point)**

Make one container for the fronend is easy, share the Dockerfile for your reference

```
#stage1
FROM node:16 as build-step

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm cache clear --force

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

#stage2
FROM nginx
COPY --from=build-step /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

But the frontend project is monorepo, same structure as this repo (https://github.com/richardtbell/microfrontend-hello-world/tree/master/packages) , there are three packages of fronends

- container
- helloReact
- helloVue

the application has different configuration for dev and prod.

```
$ cd apps/container/config
$ webpack.dev.js webpack.prod.js

...
<         publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
---
>         filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
>         publicPath: '/container/latest/'
...
21,22c18,19
<                 helloReact: 'helloReact@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js',
<                 helloVue: 'helloVue@http://localhost:8082/remoteEntry.js'
---
>                 helloReact: `helloReact@${domain}/helloReact/latest/remoteEntry.js`,
>                 helloVue: `helloVue@${domain}/helloVue/latest/remoteEntry.js`
27c24

$ cd ../../helloReact/config
$ diff webpack.dev.js webpack.prod.js

<         publicPath: 'http://localhost:8081/',
---
>         filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
>         publicPath: '/helloReact/latest/'
```

so for dev, it works locally, it use `localhost` with `port`, but this way doesn't work when we deploy to s3 bucket, so in prod configuration, set the domain name directly or use related path only.

When I want to deploy to a kubernetes cluster, what should I change? looks both configuration (dev and prod) are not suitable.

each frontend would be a set of replicate pods (via deployment/replicaset). How the frontend `publicPath` I should set?

Or in another word, how can I deploy this project (https://github.com/richardtbell/microfrontend-hello-world/tree/master/packages) to Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: Why would you need to clear the npm cache in a dockerfile?

Comment: Thanks to point it out, it is not must-have, but no hurt as well.